# Visual Studio 2005 Code Definition Window Stopped Working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

It was working fine, now it's stopped. I select a symbol in my C code and the Code Definition Window stubbonly asserts that "no definition selected". Also if I select "Go to definition" for a function then VS says "The symbol '' is not defined event though it is. The code compiles fine by the way.

Is there a known issue here?

Regards

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, I presume you've tried restarting Visual Studio or rebooting the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this problem in Visual Studio 2005 also and deleting the .ncb file seems to have done the trick. Maybe when it gets too big it simply stops functioning.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try deleting your solution.ncb file (after closing the solution)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and deleting the *.ncb file(after closing the solution) did the trick